# Which is faster - comparing values in a query or after the query

Tags: php, mysql

Which is faster to select records that are greater than zero?
This way:

```
$query = "select locale, number_field from table where locale = 'US' and number_field > 0";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
//do something
}
```

or this:

```
$query = "select locale, number_field from table where locale = 'US'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$sizearray=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($sizearray['number_field']>0){
    //do something
}
```

Note: yes I know I am using the deprecated mysql functions but I have a large site filled with queries so I haven't gotten aroundto changing 100's of queries.

Comment: Measure it empirically.

Comment: Also called _Suck it and see_

Comment: do you need values in fields locale/number_field or just check whether you have any rows at all?

Comment: I need the value,  so if it's greater than 0 I need it.  Its an INT field so if it's  a zero I want to use a default value so don't want to select that record at all.

Comment: then build index on locale/number_field and use first variant

Comment: 1. Tell the DBMS as much as you can & 2. Measure.
Generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many records are there with "number_field > 0" and whether that field is indexed or not.

An index on both locale and number_field would make it absolutely worthwhile to run in MySQL.

On the other hand, if very few records were to be rejected by the filter, then the mass of data funneled through libmysql (and possibly the network) remains the same, and the query *might* run slower. The slight delay in PHP would be more than compensated by the faster query.

In general, simple conditions with constants are always better left to the SQL.

But if you're in doubt -- **check**. Run both versions repeatedly on a representative sample of the data (or the whole of the data if you can) and time how long they require.

However, in queries like this...

```
select locale, number_field from table where locale = 'US'
```

...you don't want to add `locale` to the fields being returned. You know it's going to be "US". Also, chances are that if really you only need number_field, then the calculation(s) you're doing are so simple that you can offload them to MySQL as well, cutting down drastically on returned data and the need to loop through a resultset.